# Ist "Mäkler" im Sinne von "Vermittler" noch ein gängiges deutsches Wort?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Mit Erstaunen habe ich beim Durchblättern des [Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuches](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/BJNR001950896.html) festgestellt, dass dort konsequent von *Mäklern* (man beachte den Umlaut) und *Mäklerverträgen* im Sinne von "Vermittler" gesprochen wird. Ein *Makler*, dem dieser Begriff im gängigen Sprachgebrauch (z.B. Immobilienmakler, oder das "makeln" an Telefonanlagen) entsprechen würde, taucht darin nicht auf.

Ich kenne natürlich das Verb "mäkeln", das gebraucht wird, um auszudrücken, dass jemand beständig an etwas herumnörgelt und eine Sache schlecht macht. Im Gegensatz dazu steht das Verb "makeln", das ausschließlich für eine Vermittlungstätigkeit steht. Duden nennt das eine *selten gebraucht* als Synonym für das andere.

Aus diesem zweiten Verb ist der Begriff des *Maklers* entstanden, den ich eigentlich im Gesetz vermutet hätte, weil er (für mich) eindeutiger ist. Unter einem "Mäkler" würde ich eher einen Nörgler als einen Vermittler verstehen.

Meine Frage: Wird der *Mäkler* in einem anderen als dem juristischen Sprachgebrauch auch noch als "Vermittler" gesehen?

Comment: Das scheint nur in D so zu sein. In Österreich gibt es ein eigenes Maklergesetz: https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10003415 Dafür kommen im ABGB weder »Mäkler« noch »Makler« vor: https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10001622

Comment: Das Verb »mäkeln« ist in Österreich nicht gebräuchlich (wenn, dann noch eher im Sinn von »vermitteln« als im Sinn von »nörgeln«).

Comment: Ich kenne _mäkeln_ schon, auch wenn ich es aktiv nur mit der Vorsilbe _-be_ (bemäkeln) verwende. Im nicht fachsprachlichen Kontext verstehe ich _makeln_ als eine Funktion moderner Telephonanlagen, wo zwischen verschiedenen Gesprächen hin und her geschaltet wird.

Comment: SCNR: http://media.rbb-online.de/frz/jingles/aktuell/immobilien.mp3

Answer (score 2):

Nein, denn dieses Wort gilt seit dem 01.01.2008 als veraltet und wurde offiziell durch "Vermittler" ersetzt.

Ganz nebenbei wird dieses Wort laut Duden seit 1990 nicht mehr alltäglich, sondern nur noch zu formalen Zwecken (bis 2008) verwendet.

Comment: Wer hat es ersetzt?